# How to update the Date in datepiker dialog android?

Tags: android, datepicker

**hello,
I am developing application in android in which i am using DatePiker dialog and i tried

`@override`

`protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {`

`switch (id) {`

```
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
    {
        if(tvDate.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("--"))
        {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
        else
        {
            String _date[] = tvDate.getText().toString().split("-");
            String _monthName = _date[0];
            mMonth = helper.getMonthFromName(_monthName) -1;
            mDay = Integer.parseInt(_date[1]);
        }
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,mDateSetListener,mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }

        return null;
}
```

`@override`

`private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {`

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDate();
        if(tvRepeat.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Weekly")) {

                        tvDayName.setText(" (" + getDayNameForWeeklyRepeat() + ")");
        }
    }
};
```

`private void updateDate() {`

```
    tvDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
        .append(DateUtils.getMonthString(mMonth,DateUtils.LENGTH_SHORT))
                    .append("-")
        .append(pad(mDay)).append("-")
        .append(pad(mYear%100)));
         }
```

so `onCreateDialog` method is calling only once but when i click on next record then the DatePiker dialog is displaying the dare of the record which is displayed first time but i want to display date of new record please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // capture our View elements
        mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
        mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);

        // add a click listener to the button
        mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }
        });

        // get the current date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // display the current date
        updateDisplay();
    }
```

Override the onCreateDialog

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}
```

How to update the display:

```
// updates the date we display in the TextView
    private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
    }
```

Comment: this is working fine but if i call showDialog(id) then only once the onCreateDialog(id) is calls after click on cancel if i again call method showDialog(id) then the createDialog Method is not called  so dialog is displayed the last date which is selected last  but there is onPrepareDialog(id) is calling but i dont know how to use onPrepareDialog(id) for update the date please help me

Comment: then use updateDisplay() to change the display to the date you want