# Setting year and month in calendar

Tags: android, eclipse, calendar

I am trying to set the calendar to the year and month that is entered by the user using 2 EditTexts and for some reason am I having no luck in getting the calendar to change. Below is the method which I am working on right now. Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button change2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    change2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            change();
        }
    });
}

public void change() {
    Calendar currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

    Month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    int newmonth = Integer.parseInt(Month.getText().toString());
    int newyear = Integer.parseInt(Year.getText().toString());

    currentDate.set (Calendar.YEAR, newyear);
    currentDate.set (Calendar.MONTH, newmonth);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Months in Android-Calendar-API are based on zero-index, so you need:

```
public void change() {
  Calendar currentDate = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

  Month = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  Year = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

  int newmonth = Integer.parseInt(Month.getText().toString());
  int newyear = Integer.parseInt(Year.getText().toString());

  currentDate.set (Calendar.YEAR, newyear);
  currentDate.set (Calendar.MONTH, newmonth - 1); // here the change
}
```

You should also check if your method `change()` is called within a suitable listener, watch out for [OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setOnEditorActionListener%28android.widget.TextView.OnEditorActionListener%29). An example how to use it can be found on [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html).

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

Don't forget to use your local variable `currentDate` to update your UI. You set it until now and then you throw it away after end of method `change()`. It should be possible for you to google since I am no Android expert (just a calendar expert). I have found however, these two SO-contributions which might give you an idea:

[setting-the-date-of-a-datepicker-using-the-updatedate-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116455/setting-the-date-of-a-datepicker-using-the-updatedate-method)

[how-to-update-the-date-in-datepiker-dialog-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593963/how-to-update-the-date-in-datepiker-dialog-android)

Comment: Hi, did the change you advised me but it is still not doing anything in term of changing the calender.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my oncreate method aswell, im not sure if it has to do with the listener.

Comment: @Mark101 See my update, please. What will you finally do with variable `currentDate`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I could update it, I tried to research how to but have had no luck. All the examples i've seen stop at the currentDate.set line.

Comment: @Mark101 I have added two SO-links which hopefully help you.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I looked at the links but im still however confused on what im missing.